pytorch - RuntimeError: Expected all tensors to be on the same device, but found at least two devices, cpu and cuda:0
When I come accross kuangliu's github repo on training cifar-10 with densenet model, I want to feed the model to the gpu to accelerate the training process. However, it seems like the input tensor is found on both cpi and gpu. My suspect is that there is something wrong in the custom classes' code that makes some input tensors available on the cpu.
Could you help me point out the problem in this case? Much appreciated
For convenience, the code has a test() function to test if the network is compiled correctly or not. Here is the code:
import math
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F


class Bottleneck(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, in_planes, growth_rate):
        super(Bottleneck, self).__init__()
        self.bn1 = nn.BatchNorm2d(in_planes)
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(in_planes, 4*growth_rate, kernel_size=1, bias=False)
        self.bn2 = nn.BatchNorm2d(4*growth_rate)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(4*growth_rate, growth_rate, kernel_size=3, padding=1, bias=False)

    def forward(self, x):
        out = self.conv1(F.relu(self.bn1(x)))
        out = self.conv2(F.relu(self.bn2(out)))
        out = torch.cat([out,x], 1)
        return out


class Transition(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, in_planes, out_planes):
        super(Transition, self).__init__()
        self.bn = nn.BatchNorm2d(in_planes)
        self.conv = nn.Conv2d(in_planes, out_planes, kernel_size=1, bias=False)

    def forward(self, x):
        out = self.conv(F.relu(self.bn(x)))
        out = F.avg_pool2d(out, 2)
        return out


class DenseNet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, block, nblocks, growth_rate=12, reduction=0.5, num_classes=10):
        super(DenseNet, self).__init__()
        self.growth_rate = growth_rate

        num_planes = 2*growth_rate
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(3, num_planes, kernel_size=3, padding=1, bias=False)

        self.dense1 = self._make_dense_layers(block, num_planes, nblocks[0])
        num_planes += nblocks[0]*growth_rate
        out_planes = int(math.floor(num_planes*reduction))
        self.trans1 = Transition(num_planes, out_planes)
        num_planes = out_planes

        self.dense2 = self._make_dense_layers(block, num_planes, nblocks[1])
        num_planes += nblocks[1]*growth_rate
        out_planes = int(math.floor(num_planes*reduction))
        self.trans2 = Transition(num_planes, out_planes)
        num_planes = out_planes

        self.dense3 = self._make_dense_layers(block, num_planes, nblocks[2])
        num_planes += nblocks[2]*growth_rate
        out_planes = int(math.floor(num_planes*reduction))
        self.trans3 = Transition(num_planes, out_planes)
        num_planes = out_planes

        self.dense4 = self._make_dense_layers(block, num_planes, nblocks[3])
        num_planes += nblocks[3]*growth_rate

        self.bn = nn.BatchNorm2d(num_planes)
        self.linear = nn.Linear(num_planes, num_classes)

    def _make_dense_layers(self, block, in_planes, nblock):
        layers = []
        for i in range(nblock):
            layers.append(block(in_planes, self.growth_rate))
            in_planes += self.growth_rate
        return nn.Sequential(*layers)

    def forward(self, x):
        out = self.conv1(x)
        out = self.trans1(self.dense1(out))
        out = self.trans2(self.dense2(out))
        out = self.trans3(self.dense3(out))
        out = self.dense4(out)
        out = F.avg_pool2d(F.relu(self.bn(out)), 4)
        out = out.view(out.size(0), -1)
        out = self.linear(out)
        return out

def densenet_cifar():
    return DenseNet(Bottleneck, [6,12,24,16], growth_rate=12)

def test():
    device = torch.device('cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')
    net = densenet_cifar().to(device)
    x = torch.randn(1,3,32,32)
    y = net(x)
    print(y)

test()

Have a great day!

You need to move the x tensor to the same device.
Change x = torch.randn(1,3,32,32) to x = torch.randn(1,3,32,32).to(device)

Thanks, Karl. It works for this example.

I also noticed that in my other example, when I created an instance of a class in the forward() method (e.g: conv1 = nn.Conv2d()), it has the same error. But when I moved that instantiate line to init, it works perfectly!
